# How to set the (initial) size of PhosphorJS Widgets

Tags: javascript, widget, dockpanel

How do you set the (initial) size of a PhosphorJS Widget, specifically widgets inside a [DockPanel](http://phosphorjs.github.io/examples/dockpanel/)?

You can resize them manually, but I would like to set their size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Some widgets, like the [SplitPanel](http://phosphorjs.github.io/phosphor-splitpanel/api/), have a [`setSizes()`](http://phosphorjs.github.io/phosphor-splitpanel/api/classes/splitpanel.html#setsizes) method.**

In the example linked in the question, the CodeMirror panel could be resized like so (other panels will take more digging through the hierarchy):

```
// First, find the parent widget:

stackedLayout  = panel.layout                
dockSplitPanel = stackedLayout._children[0]

// OR directly: panel.layout._children[0]


// Then set the relative sizes so the CodeMirror panel takes 60% of the width:
dockSplitPanel.setSizes([6,4])
```